# Drupal embed view in email sent by views

Tags: views, commerce, rules, emails

I've configured a rule to send an email after a commerce order is placed containing products of a particular type. That works fine. The body though is a view token ([views:embed:golf_registration_information:default]) pulling in specific order info (couldn't do this through the rule with the info I wanted to include). However in the email, I'm getting "edit view" links in a few places, which obviously I don't want.

Here's what the link looks like: http://website.com/admin/structure/views/view/golf_registration_information/edit/default?destination=checkout/451/paypal_ec

I can't figure out how they are getting in there. Is there a setting I'm missing in Views? It appears as the first thing in the body, and then within the body above the line items table. Obviously I didn't add anything within the Global Custom Text field that's outputting the fields.

Modules I'm using: D7, Commerce, Commerce Rules Extra, Rules, Mimemail, Views, Token Embed Views

Comment: Can you show the email, too?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sounds like you need to disable contextual links:

[image]

Comment: Well that got rid of the top link. The one in the body still exists. Going to investigate further... Thanks!